# VSCode chaining regex transforms in a snippet

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to transform a filename automatically in VSCode in two ways.
Let's say I have `test-file-name.md`, I want to end up with `Test File Name` in my document.
Right now I can do both part of the transform separately but I'm struggling to find how to combine them.

1. To remove all the `-` and replace them with a space I do this: `${TM_FILENAME_BASE/[-]/ /g}`
2. And for capitalizing the first letter of each word I do: `${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(\b[a-z])/${1:/upcase}/g}` (the `\b` is probably useless in this case I guess)

I've tried multiples way of writing them together but I can't find a way to have them one after the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`"body": "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([^-]+)(-*)/${1:/capitalize}${2:+ }/g}"`

Because of the `g` flag it will get all the occurrences and do each transform of the two capture groups multiple time.  In your test case `(test-)(file-)(name)` that would be three times.  It should work for any number of hyphenated words.

`([^-]+)` everything up to a hyphen.

`${1:/capitalize}` capitalize capture group 1.

`${2:+ }` means if there is a 2nd capture group, the `(-*)`, add a space.  I added this because at the end there is no hyphen - and thus there will be no 2nd capture group and thus no extra space should be added at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had managed after more tries to get "Test File Name " but was still struggling to find how not to have the last space.