# what's wrong with this chained snippet for visual studio code?

Tags: regex, vscode-snippets

i am trying to make a snippet to declare bemit components so when i create a new one, i just have to write the prefix "new-bemit-component" and then for example with the file "_c-indice" _ for partial element, c- for component and then the name, the snippet would write:

```
/* ========================================================================================= */
/* COMPONENT - C INDICE */
/* ========================================================================================= */

.c-indice{
    
}

/* ========================================================================================= */
/* END COMPONENT - C INDICE */
/* ========================================================================================= */
```

I'd done that the snippet writes

/* ========================================================================================= */
/* COMPONENT - C indice */
/* ========================================================================================= */

.c-indice{

}

/* ========================================================================================= */
/* END COMPONENT - C indice */
/* ========================================================================================= */

using

```
"body": [
          "/* ========================================================================================= */",
          "/* COMPONENT - C ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/_c-//} */",
          "/* ========================================================================================= */",
          "",
          ".${TM_FILENAME_BASE/[\\\\_]//}{",
          "",
          "}",
          "",
          "/* ========================================================================================= */",
          "/* END COMPONENT - C ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/_c-//} */",
          "/* ========================================================================================= */"
        ],
```

but now i am trying to chain another regex so the result ends in upper-case, using this

```
"body": [
          "/* ========================================================================================= */",
          "/* COMPONENT - C ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(_c-)(\\(?!_\\w\b)\b\\w+)/${1:+ }/g ${2:/capitalize/}} */",
          "/* ========================================================================================= */",
          "",
          ".${TM_FILENAME_BASE/[\\\\_]//}{",
          "",
          "}",
          "",
          "/* ========================================================================================= */",
          "/* END COMPONENT - C ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/_c-//} */",
          "/* ========================================================================================= */"
        ],
```

Just like they did here [VSCode chaining regex transforms in a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66507762/vscode-chaining-regex-transforms-in-a-snippet)

But must be there something wrong with the regex and i get this:

```
/* ========================================================================================= */
/* COMPONENT - C ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(_c-)(\(?!_\w)\w+)/+ /g /capitalize/} */
/* ========================================================================================= */

.c-indice{

}

/* ========================================================================================= */
/* END COMPONENT - C indice */
/* ========================================================================================= */
```

I tested the regex with https://regex101.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture only the part after `_c-` and uppercase it:

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/_c-(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}
```

The `_c-` in the `TM_FILENAME_BASE` variable will be matched, and the rest will be captured into Group 1.

Then, all matched text will be replaced (once, no `g` flag) with the contents of Group 1 turned to upper case with `upcase`.